# How to run Selenium on another PC without IDE

Tags: python, selenium

is it possible to run Selenium script on another computer that doesn't have IDE installed? (the other PC only has Python installed)
How do I do that?
Or is it mandatory to use IDE?

I tried to run the Selenium script on another computer without the IDE installed... It identifies that it is Selenium but cannot actually enter a web page.

Comment: What makes you think Selenium needs an IDE? Just run `python3 your_selenium_script.py`, assuming you've installed selenium and the command is `python3` rather than `python`. If you have a script you ran but it didn't work, please show the script as a [mcve], describe what it's supposed to do and what actually happened and share any relevant environment details. Thanks.

Comment: Depending on which backend you're using (and whether it's headless), you may need a GUI available (not necessarily a real one; tools like x11vnc can be used to provide a "fake" GUI), but you certainly don't need an IDE. Anyhow -- the description of the problem is so vague that this can't possibly be answered in its current state; as ggorlen says above, we need to know _how_ you determined selenium not to be working in enough detail that we can cause the problem ourselves, and determine with 100% certainty that we're seeing the _same_ problem, not just a generally-similar one.

Comment: If you just want to execute the script on another machine, you can use Selenium Grid concept. Explain your scenario clearly.